# Proper way to put a swf on the page

Tags: html, flash, embed

I recently noticed that SWF objects on our site are being downloaded twice, so I'm trying to determine if there's a more correct way to embed them.  My current code is:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/movie.swf" width="635" height="350" class="ad">
  <param name="movie" value="/movie.swf" />
  <param value="high" name="quality">
  <param value="#FFFFFF" name="bgcolor">
  <param value="always" name="allowScriptAccess">
  <param value="clickTAG=http://www.google.com/" name="FlashVars">
  <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
</object>
```

Looking at some of the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499432/is-there-a-standard-copy-paste-way-to-safely-put-a-swf-in-a-web-page) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322864/how-to-embded-a-swf-on-a-html-page) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418446/how-to-put-flash-swf-in-a-page/1418457#1418457) here on SO, it seems that this is the standard way of doing this, but having them downloaded twice is putting unnecessary strain on my servers. Is this the best way to embed a swf on our pages? If not, a better method would definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web blog site Alistapart has a great article "[Flash Satay](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/flashsatay)" which goes into great detail on all the issues with different flash embedding techniques.

They conclude that your method is the simplest way to achieve it.